# android how to make a textview to fill layout both vertically and horizintly

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to design a layout with one image and one Text View but Text View should fill the remaining area both horizontally and vertically depending upon the length of the text.
Right now I am able to fill the space vertically only.
any help would be great help for me!!

here is the layout:
i want minimum 100dp width and max 230dp if available

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/wine_image"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/wine_name"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/wine_image"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxWidth="250dp"
            android:minWidth="100dp"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:textColor="@color/yellow"
            android:textSize="8sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/winedetailstext"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/wine_name"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/wine_image"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="100"
            android:maxWidth="230dp"
            android:minWidth="100dp"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="8sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: please post reference image so SO user can know.

Answer (score 0):

Use TextView's property `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` and for width  use `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` and use parent layout a `Relative layout`
it will work for you

Answer (score 0):

make sure the propeties of Parent is also set to

```
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

and for TextView do the following

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 />
```